# How to implement parallel long running background tasks in .NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have .NET Core *console* application containing two independent tasks that should be running in parallel for the entire life-time of the application. I was thinking to use [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1):

```
class BackgroundTaskOne : BackgroundService
{
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                // do long running task for the entire life-time of application
                while(true)
                {
                    // do work one
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

class BackgroundTaskTwo : BackgroundService
{
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                // do long running task for the entire life-time of application
                while(true)
                {
                    // do work two
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And register them like this:

```
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundTaskOne>();
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundTaskTwo>();
```

But these are going to run *in order*. So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make these two run in parallel?
2. Are there any other alternatives to run two long-running background processes in .NET Core in parallel?

Comment: Have you look at MSDN's [Task-based asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)?  Lots of good ideas in there.  You can create Tasks, you can create whole Threads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of [`BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_BackgroundService_ExecuteAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) say

> The implementation should return a task that represents the lifetime of the long running operation(s) being performed.

Your implementation returns a completed task when the whole work is done. In fact you implemented it to run sync and not async and that is the reason for not running parallel.

Here is a sample implementation with some fake async work:

```
class BackgroundTaskOne : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                // do work one
                await Task.Delay( 100 );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Actually the work I am performing in the try block is the actual long-running task that needs to be running for the entire lifetime of the application (just updated the question), so awaing that wouldn't help. I want to fire and forget these two tasks.

Comment: It does not matter how long the task is running, you have to have a real task and not a sync operation and returning a completed task at the end

Answer (score 1):

As documentation says:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/hosted-services.md

> No further services are started until ExecuteAsync becomes
>   asynchronous, such as by calling `await`.

As long as you do not have `async` clause mentioned at the `ExecuteAsync` method above, I suspect your method is synchronous at whole. This is why two services are called sequentially, not in parallel. Give them a break, introduce good amount of awaitable code.